# Reactivity gone in meteor + iron-router app when returning to page with back button

Tags: meteor, iron-router

In my app I have a page with some reactive elements that are updating ok when the underlying data changes.
If I leave the page to go to some other page in the app using (Iron Router) Router.go(...) and then return to the previous page with the browser back button, the reactivity is gone. Page elements no longer update after data changes.
Only after hitting the browser refresh button everything is ok again.
Is this to be expected or can someone give me a clue on what I could have done wrong?

Comment: Are you using the latest meteor / iron-router version? I remember this problem was affecting IR long time ago.

Comment: @apendua: yes, everything is 1.0

Comment: Sounds like state is incorrectly restored. If you can reduce the code to a simple example and push a reproduction repo, the [iron:router team would love to look at the issue](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues).

Comment: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/1087